# Android - Calling a method in other process

Tags: android, process, ipc, rpc

I have 2 Activities, each Activity has its own process.
For example, Activity_1 is the **main_process** and Activity_2 is a **separated_process**.
From AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity_2"
            android:process="${separated_process}"
...>
</activity>
```

Activity_2 has a method:

```
public static boolean isActive() {
        return LastResume > LastPaused;
    }
```

I am trying to call isActive() from Activity_1, something like:

```
public static void stuffToDo() {
        //some calculations
        if (Activity_2.isActive()) {...}
        //more calculations
    }
```

What is the best way to perform that action?

Comment: What you want is not possible. You need to use some form of IPC (inter-process communication). The main options for that include: starting an activity, starting a service, binding to a service (and then calling functions on the exposed `Binder`), sending a broadcast, and various forms of talking to a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks.
Can you share an implementation example?